# Need help finding dataset whose original source is removed

Tags: data-request

[Energy Consumption in schools Dundee](https://data.dundeecity.gov.uk/en_GB/dataset/energy-consumption-of-schools/resource/96e14a3c-4828-49fd-a69a-057d8f99bc85)

I need this dataset for a project. The original source has been removed. I couldnt find any references to it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just for the record, https://web.archive.org/ has no record of https://data.dundeecity.gov.uk/en_GB/dataset/ or resources under that path.

Comment: If you search that URL with duckduckgo.com you get a short summary of the data linking to the broken page, but google.com yields nothing. Still digging

Comment: @tripleee There is actually now one record because you searched for it :) It's a 404 page.

Comment: If you google `"Energy usage recorded every half hour for primary and high school campuses in Dundee City"` (in quotes), you MAY find some other sources. I found a few summaries, and one direct link on datasetguide.com but I couldn't connect to that site due to an HTTPS error https://cpag.org.uk/sites/default/files/Cost%20of%20the%20School%20Day%20Dundee%20-%20Full%20Report.pdf is the closest I got (still works, but just a summary)